# Combined Formattable with KableExtra

Tags: r-markdown, kableextra, formattable

I am trying to create a table that combines features from `Formattable` with `KableExtra`. I have found a number of examples which have helped but doesn't quite do everything I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
library(KableExtra)
library(Formattable)
```

```
df <- structure(list(Income_source = c("A", "B", "C", "C"), Jul = c(1777.01, 
                                                              0.13, 9587.39, 11364.53), Aug = c(0, 0.09, 9908.78, 9908.87), 
               Sep = c(5374.6, 0.03, 9859.87, 15234.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Example of the `Formattable` function I'd like to apply. Note the color_tile is applied specifically to each row

```
formattable(df, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) {
  area(row, col = 1:nrow(df)) ~ color_tile("transparent", "pink")
}))
```

[image]

The example I found which lets me combine `Formattable` with `KableExtra` looks like this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Jul = formattable::color_tile("transparent", "pink")(Jul),
         Aug = formattable::color_tile("transparent", "pink")(Aug),
         Sep = formattable::color_tile("transparent", "pink")(Sep)) %>% 
  select(Name,everything()) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F,format.args = list(big.mark = ",",scientific = FALSE)) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Cambria") %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) %>% 
  row_spec(0, bold = T)
```

[image]

The problems with this solution is:

1: The color_tile function is applied to columns rather than rows
2: The numeric values drop the commas

The table I'm planning on generating would be updated monthly so that next month the data for October would be presented, followed by November and so forth.  As such I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require me to edit the script each time i.e. mutate the new data. Hopefully that makes sense.

List item